# Unwanted bash newline nixos

Tags: bash, nix, nixos

I have installed NixOS 18.03.

Bash seems to add a newline after every command.

```
$ echo Hello, world!
Hello, world!

$
```

Why is this? How can I stop it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, it adds a newline before the prompt by default, by setting

```
PS1="\n\[\033[$PROMPT_COLOR\][\u@\h:\w]\\$\[\033[0m\] "
```

You can set a more reasonable prompt by configuring the option [programs.bash.promptInit](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/options.html#opt-programs.bash.promptInit).

Answer (score 2):

It's the default prompt in NixOS, it will always append newline a the end.

```
PS1="$ "
```